# How to obtain a valid pointer to a QLineEdit in another process?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5, findwindow

I'm writing a *Win32* application that automates text input for several `QLineEdit` controls of a Qt program running in another process.

```
#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qwindow.h>
#include <qguiapplication.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "qt5core.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "qt5gui.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "qt5widgets.lib")

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    HWND hMainWindow = FindWindow(L"Qt5QWindowIcon", L"Target QtApp");
    if (hMainWindow != NULL)
    {
        QWindow* pWin = QWindow::fromWinId((WId)hMainWindow);
        QLineEdit* pEdit = pWin->findChild<QLineEdit*>();
        if (pEdit != NULL)
        {
            pEdit->setText("Hello");
        }
        else
        {
            QList<QLineEdit*> list = pWin->findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
            if (!list.empty())
            {
                for (QLineEdit* pEdit : list)
                {
                    pEdit->setText("Hello");
                }
            }
            else MessageBox(NULL, L"List is empty.", L"Info", 0);
        }
    }

    app.exec();
}
```

In the code above, I obtain a window handle (`HWND`) to the main window of the Qt app using the *Win32* function `FindWindow()`. I get a valid handle with that call, then I convert it to a `QWindow*` pointer with `QWindow::findWinId()`.

That call also returns a valid `QWindow*` pointer, which I then use to call:

- `QWindow::findChild<QLineEdit*>()`
- `QWindow::findChildren<QLineEdit*>()`
- `findChildren<QWidget*>()`

However, all of these methods always return `NULL` or an empty list.

Why is this the case?

If this is not really possible with the code above, how to achieve what I'm trying to do in *Win32*, or maybe even in Qt?

---

**Notes:**

1. The target Qt application is 32-bit, that's why I'm using Qt version 5.15.2, which is the last version that supports 32-bit Qt projects.
2. I do not have direct access to the code of the target Qt application whose `QLineEdit` controls I'm trying to automate.

Comment: Pointers are valid only in the process whose virtual address space they refer to. You cannot get a pointer in process A to an object in process B. If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) and keep your fingers crossed that Qt doesn't fail you.

Comment: What are you trying to test your UI or your business logic? If it is your business logic isolate it from your UI and unit test that first.

Comment: @PepijnKramer *"I do not have direct access to the code of the target Qt application"*.

Comment: Windows of a separate process are *alien* windows, the QWindow you get is just the internal handler Qt can use to access the underlying OS window, but that doesn't mean that you can directly access its contents. In fact, you can't, as they don't even share the same memory space, and Qt has no means to even "know" that the other window is actually a Qt managed one.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I have a question for IInspectable and musicamante. What if we inject the code into the target Qt process using SetWindowHookEx function? So, I  write the code that obtains the pointers to QLineEdit in an exported DLL function and then write another program that performs the injection, so that the DLL function is called, for example, during a mouse or window event in the Qt process. Since it's a DLL, I'm assuming that the code will be added in the Qt process's address space. Will the code now be able to access the shared data like those own by QLineEdit? Thanks.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I'm trying to automate text input for those QLineEdit controls in another app built with Qt. Also, I forgot to mention in my post that I managed to obtain the window handles (HWND) of those QLineEdit controls via  EnumChildWindow. It seems to me that QLineEdit is built on top of Win32 Edit control. However, each time I send those controls a WM_GETTEXT message, supplying a pointer to a string buffer, I get names like "unit_lineEditWindow" and "quantity_lineEditWindow" -- not the actual texts displayed in the controls. This isn't the normal behavior with Win32 edit controls.

Comment: Injecting code into the target process is not nearly sufficient. You will still have to find where the target process stores those pointers (calling `fromWinId()` will fail for the same reasons). And when that is done, you need to find a time when it's safe to make modifications. This ultimately means getting your code to run on the same thread that owns the widgets. That's a lot of *really* hard problems to solve. UI Automation is far easier to use. Try [inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to see if the required interfaces are implemented.

Comment: @IInspectable, I clicked that link you shared me for Inspect.exe, but according to Microsoft, Inspect is a legacy tool. So I downloaded Accessibility Insights as it recommended, ran the program and pointed the cursor to one of the QLineEdit controls in the target Qt app. And immediately under the "Patterns" panel in  Accessibility Insight, I could see the actual content of the QLineEdit that I pointed. You can see a screenshot here: https://imageupload.io/DaU4xDZ3O6DoUch
The value is "7014.33" which refers to a length of an object.

Comment: @IInspectable My question now is, how is it able to extract the value from a QLineEdit control that's on another process? And how can I achieve the same thing with my Win32 program (extract the value)? Thanks again for helping me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: My first comment links to the reference documentation. That's a fair amount of information to digest (you can skip the "provider programmer's guide"). UI Automation establishes a contract between "providers" and "clients": "Providers" are required to supply data in a way that can cross process boundaries. "Clients" use formalized interfaces to navigate the accessible tree, query information, or submit actions. The details of interprocess communication are handled by the system. UI Automation is independent of the concrete UI framework in use.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, @IInspectable!  I noticed that all of the QLineEdit controls that I checked with Accessibility Insights have an "IsReadOnly" value of "True," so they can't be changed, or I can't submit an action to change their string values. Although I said I wanted to automate text input with my software, but as long as I could extract the texts from the Qt app through UI Automation, I could present the texts to automate within my software. I could run the Qt app hidden in the background, extract the text data, modify them if necessary and display them in my program.

Comment: That will do for me! Again, @IInspectable, thank you for your time to answer all my questions. I greatly appreciate it. Thanks, too, to musicanmante and Pepjin Kramer.

Comment: @IInspectable  I would like to accept your answer, but I couldn't do that since it's a comment.